# Stop a variable from subtracting for a few seconds

Tags: java

I'm new to java and have a problem in my code. I have two objects moving towards each other ("Gegener" is one of them) and everytime they touch, the variable "leben" should be shortened by 1. The problem is that the variable is shortened for every pixel that they touch. I want the variable shortened by 1 and then an unsubtractable timeperiod. I already tried Thread.sleep(); but it didn't worked well.

This is the code so far:

```
public void damage()
{
    Actor Gegner = (Actor) getOneObjectAtOffset(0, (getImage().getHeight()/2)+3, Gegner.class);
    {
        if(Gegner != zero)
        {
            getWorld().removeObject(Gegner2);
        }
        if(isTouching(Gegner.class))
        {
            if(touching== false)
            {
                leben = leben-1;
                touching= true;
                getWorld().removeObject(Gegner);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            touching= false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When it touch, store the current time, then on later event just check if current time has exceed the stored time + whatever period you need

Comment: Comment by Martheen is correct. If a resolution of milliseconds (Java 8) or microseconds (Java 9+) suffices, use `Instant.now` and `Duration.between`. If nanosecond resolution is needed, use `System.nanoTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a timer to this (and mixing display/game update - which makes things like slowing it down, running simulations faster, etc. more difficult) why not just add a 'counter' for when you check `touching`?

As pseudo code ('cause I don't have enough context to be more useful):

```java
private int touchCooldown = 0;

public void damage() {

    if (touchCooldown > 0) {
        touchCooldown--;
        return;
    } 

    if (actor1.isTouching(actor2)) {
        actor1.life--;
        touchCooldown = 5;
    }
}
```